# for loop in R not pasting into sections of list

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Lets say I have a list that has different lengths per section

```
[[1]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

[[2]]
[2] 0 0 0 0
```

In reality this list has millions of elements per section.

I now use two for loops to populate the list.

**i** takes on the length of the list (2 in this example.)

**j** takes on the length of each section of the list (so 10 and 4 here), based on where **i** is at.

```
for(i in 1:length(testlist)){
for(j in 1:length(testlist[[i]]$ToBeDeleted)){


emptylist2[i] <- paste(testlist[[i]]$ToBeDeleted[j],   

testlist[[i]]$ReasonToBeDeleted[j], sep=";")


  }}
```

Please try to ignore the variable names, they are not important.

The output is not what I desire. It looks (in the reproducible example context) like this:

```
[[1]
[1] 0;NA

[[2]]
[2] 0;Na
```

The loops have only posted one "element" to each section of the list, they have not populated the whole list.

What I would like to see (where the numbers and text take on many different values) is this:

```
[[1]
[1] 0;NA 0;test1 0;NA 1;variable 1;etc 0;randomname 0;NA 0;Na 0;nA 0;na 

[[2]]
[2] 1;frfrf 0;na 0;na 0;na
```

**HERE IS A REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

```
x <- vector("list", 2)
x[[1]] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
x[[2]] <- c(0,0,0,0)

z <- vector("list", 2)
z[[1]] <- c(0,0,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
z[[2]] <- c("a","b","c","d")

emptylist2 <- vector("list", 2)



for(i in 1:length(emptylist2)){
for(j in 1:length(x)){


x[i] <- paste(z[[i]][j], z[[i]][j], sep=";")


}}
```

Which, as pointed out, is fixed by changing x[i] to x[[i]][j]

Comment: Please show a reproducible example

Comment: In each step, your emptylist2 is updated with the j-th value. Try  `emptylist2[[i]][j]`,

Comment: @nya, this worked. great diagnostic skills.

Comment: Nested for loops often end up with similar kinds or typos/oversights. Happy to find something good out of my past frustrations.